# SQLite Select Statement - Where two conditions are met?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

Can someone please correct my select statement, the below works selecting everything from table 'games' where 'genre=fps'.

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM games WHERE genre=fps', [], renderResults);
```

I don't know how to, or if it is possible to expand upon this to to select everything where 'genre=fps' and 'decade=90' - something like this:

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM games WHERE genre=fps AND decade=90', [], renderResults);
```

or

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM games WHERE genre=fps AND WHERE decade=90', [], renderResults);
```

Is the above possible? This is probably really straightforward but I cant find any examples or tutorials to follow.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt is correct, however if fps is a text value you need quotes around it:

```
 SELECT * FROM games WHERE genre = 'fps' AND decade = 90
```